# jquery: disable submit button in a form and enable it onChange of any element on the form

Tags: jquery

I need to disable the disable the submit button on my form and to enable if the onchange event occurs for any other input on the form 
so basically I need to:

- disable the submit button
- add a method that enbales the submit button to the onchange event for all the other inputs on the form

anybody knows how to do this ? (especially the second one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery 1.4:

```
// To disable submit button
$('#myform').find (':submit').attr ('disabled', 'disabled');

// Re-enable submit
var form = $('#myform');
$(':input', form.get(0)).live ('change', function (e) {
    form.find (':submit').removeAttr ('disabled');
});
```

Comment: @Omu I know this is really old but its exactly what im trying to do! One problem i found, the onchange applies to the submit button, so if the submit button is disabled, and i simply click it, it is now enabled. Did you find a bypass for that?

Comment: @Jonah Katz don't know but (a quick thought) try $('input[type="text"],select').live('change',function(e) { ... instead of what it written there, or ask a new question

Comment: @Omu Already did! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352139/disable-submit-button-untill-any-form-element-change

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}).find(":input").change(function() {
    $(this).parent("form").find(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$("#myform").children().change(function(){
   $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```